# Is there something like @PostConstruct in plain java?

Tags: java

I have an class A and B like this:

```
public static class A {
    public A() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }

    public void init() {
        System.out.println("RUN AFTER CONSTRUCTOR");
    }
}

public static class B extends A {
    public B() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new B();
}
```

I want that A and all subclasses of A run a piece of code AFTER the constructor has finished.

Is it possible without adding Spring/AspectJ or something like that?

Comment: Just call init () at the end of your constructor

Comment: But i don't want to repeat it in every subclass, and it should be called after even the subclass constructor has finished

Comment: You can use reflection to find the method annotated @PostConstrcut

Comment: @wutzebaer could you make your subclass call super()?

Comment: @DavidBrossard this would call the method after the super constructor but before the sub constructor.. it must be called after the sub constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Plain Java doesn't provide similarly hook methods.
`@PostConstruct` available in bean containers was initially designed to perform an init processing after dependency injection is done.
As the container performs for you the instantiation (and the destruction) of the beans, it has so a way to execute code after their instantiation (or before their destruction : `@PreDestroy`).

> But i don't want to repeat it in every subclass, and it should be
>   called after even the subclass constructor has finished

If each constructor invocation of the hierarchy has to perform a specific processing, you have to specify that in each class or base class.

Comment: I would argue it's the other way around. `@PostConstruct` is necessary because there is no other proper place to put code which relies on the object having finished initialization (because the constructor isn't as relevant in a di container setting).

Comment: @daniu Indeed It was misleading. I updated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidBrossard said, on Vanilla Java, you can call init() at the end of the constructor, to execute like a `@PostConstruct`